# Is it possible to pass a NULL NSError** to a Swift function that throws?

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling

In Objective-C, it's expected that you can pass in `NULL` to any `NSError**` parameter to ignore the error. However, when I try to pass `NULL` to a Swift method that throws an error, it generates a runtime error.

```
// Thrower.swift
class Thrower: NSObject {
    static func throwError() throws {
        throw NSError(domain: "bla", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    }
}

...

// AppDelegate.m
BOOL success = [Thrower throwErrorAndReturnError:NULL];
```

This generates an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error, with this stack:

[image]

I'm a little surprised at this behavior. I would expect this to either work, or the compiler to generate a warning when you pass `NULL` to one of these methods.

Here's what the generated header of the Swift method looks like:

`+ (BOOL)throwErrorAndReturnError:(NSError * __nullable * __null_unspecified)error;`

If this was not supposed to work, why wouldn't they generate `NSError * __nullable * __nonnull`, so that a compiler warning is generated when you try to pass in a nullable `NSError*`?

Is there something I'm missing here, or is this just expected behavior?

Comment: The error throw is there for a reason:to help you with bugs, don't you think that is a good idea? Handling all potential errors is the job of a real developer, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [WWDC'15 Session 401](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-401/) (Swift and Objective-C Interoperability) Doug Gregor said:

> This means, 'I thought about it, I couldn't come to an answer.' The best thing to do is keep it implicitly unwrapped optional in Swift, keep it null-unspecified here.

So, basically, your null is mapped to `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ErrorType>.None`, that pretty much explains the crash.

On the session above they mention `NSError **` is assumed to be `nullable` on both pointers. Apparently they've changed their mind or the mapping is not symmetrical, anyway it looks wrong to me.

Considering that behavior and not being `NSError * __nullable * __nonnull` I'd say it's a bug, I'd open a radar. If you do please let us know so we can dupe it.

Comment: Thanks, feels like a bug to me too. I filed radar [24498034](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5013748225933312).